# Does TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() mean the context of the class?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I used to use Dispatcher or setting the SynchronizationSetting but since switching to PCL (Profile 158), I'm left with FromCurrentSynchronization, Default or Current. I think that FromCurrentSynchronization means the syncContext of the class. Is that true? How do I check it?

Currently the class uses

```
    private async Task asyncInvoke(Action action)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

If I stick this in a utility class, will it end up picking up the syncContext of the utility class?

Comment: Synchronization context is a property of a *thread*, not a class.

Comment: A class when instantiated is in a thread which has a syncContext. If I ask for "CurrentSynchronizationContext" whose thread is it coming from? From the thread of the caller? the thread of the class that was instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

`FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` is what you're looking for. It is not related to a "class" at all.

As Hans stated, one way of thinking of it is that it's a property of the current thread.

In your case, a `Dispatcher`-based UI will provide a `SynchronizationContext` for the UI thread that is tied to the dispatcher. An easy way to verify this is to check out `SynchronizationContext.Current.GetType().Name`.

However, I recommend that you consider a more radical approach. You're currently trying to update the UI from background thread logic. Try to restructure your code so that your background thread logic is not aware of the UI at all (e.g., see [the Progress Reporting section on this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). If you can do this, you'll find that your code is more testable and has better separation of concerns.

Comment: The problem here is that there is a database that I must always access from the database thread. I need to make sure that however this class is called, the database calls must run on the database thread. But I am doing this in PCL and my previous methods (to invoke the Dispatcher that was there when the class started) no longer works.

Comment: Incidentally, SetSynchronizationSetting(mySyncSetting) would be promising but it is not in Profile 158.

Comment: If you have a threading restriction like that, the best option is to use a dedicated thread that you create specifically for the database access. If you install my `Nito.AsyncEx` NuGet library, you can use my [`AsyncContextThread` type](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext).